# MIPS | Pseudo Instructions

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

Why were pseudo instructions written into MIPS assembly code? Why can't instructions like *bge, b, mul, beqz* be written in a non-pseudo format?

Comment: They can be written in non-pseudo of course. The pseudos are for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

they can.  it is just like directives or macros or other labor saving solutions.

pseudo instructions are not part of the instruction set necessarily they are part of the assembly language which is defined by the assembler, not the hardware nor ip vendor/inventor.  Up to the assembler author(s) to define its instruction set.